# FFMPEG to stream to rtmp

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, rtmp

I am streaming a file from hard disk to rtmp server. What i need is to stream a file from the client PC. i.e., I am hosting ffmpeg on the server and my web application streams the file from the client PC to the rtmp server. Is it possible? I don't want to upload the file to my server.

Answer (score 0):

[possible duplicate of another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11647868/using-ffmpeg-to-stream-continuously-videos-files-to-a-rtmp-server)

or look at avconv/ffmpeg

[avconv documentation --> rtmp section](https://libav.org/avconv.html#librtmp-rtmp_002c-rtmpe_002c-rtmps_002c-rtmpt_002c-rtmpte)

-re is realtime
-i is input file
-f is input file type
last parameter is the rtmp destination

```
For example, to stream a file in real-time to an RTMP server using avconv:
avconv -re -i myfile -f flv rtmp://myserver/live/mystream

To play the same stream using avplay:
avplay "rtmp://myserver/live/mystream live=1"
```

[ffmpeg website](https://www.ffmpeg.org/documentation.html)
supposedly, ffmpeg is being replaced by avconv but it still seems to be an active project

[try google](https://www.google.com/search?q=avconv%20ubuntu&oq=avconv&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0j69i59j0l2.1496j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=stream%20video%20to%20rtmp%20server)

Comment: i like to stream from client pc, in ur example "myfile" , how to use tht file from web client pc without uploading them entirely  to the server?

Comment: Libav is a fork of FFmpeg that had their own so-called "`ffmpeg`". Then they eventually replaced it with `avconv`. The deprecated message provided by Libav (and the additional message from the  Ubuntu maintainer) were worded poorly and confusing to users. `ffmpeg` from FFmpeg is actively developed.

Comment: is it possible to use other remote server as RTMP server? rtmp://OTHER_server/live/mystream ?